# Copy one file from assets to sd

Tags: android, android-assets

I want to copy ONE file "test.txt" to the SD card.

I found tips on how to copy more than one, but they are not working for me...

The file is in the root of the assets folder "/test.txt"

Thanks.

Comment: Does you application have permissions to access the SD card?

Comment: In what way are the tutorials "not working" for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a native command for that, but you can always create a `File`, open the file you want to copy, and copy de byte array from one to another.